# Do I have to set up Virtual Host when Apache accessed locally?

Tags: networking, apache2, lamp

For the testing purposes I'm setting up LAMP on one machine. I want to access  Apache, MySQL and PHP from the same machine. Is it necessary to set up a Virtual Host?

Comment: No. The default "host" should be enough.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli That's not a comment!  *That's an answer!*  Please post an answer, ping me [at]Fabby and I'll come back and upvote! **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby - I added an answer. Please, add any comments to it for any clarifications that you may need.

Answer (score 1):

After you have installed **Apache Web Server** to your machine, you will have a *default* site configuration in the file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
    ServerAdmin ...
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
...
    ErrorLog ...
    CustomLog ...
</VirtualHost>
```

By appropriately editing this configuration (for example, the `DocumentRoot` directive) and restarting Apache Web Server, you will have a working web server configuration with no virtual hosts.

Any web page request coming to TCP port 80 will be served from the default directory specified on `DocumentRoot` directive. This is the simplest configuration that works.

The web page request can be send to the "*host*" (for example: `http://host/page`) using any of the following as `host`:

```
127.0.0.1
[::1]
localhost
```

if you are accessing it from the *same* machine.

If you want to access it from *another* machine, you can use

```
ip_addr
host_name
```

where

`ip_addr` is the IPv4 or IPv6 of the web server as known by the requesting machine. (A TCP access path to port 80 of your server should be available from your web "browser" machine.)

`host_name` can be a simple or fully qualified name that resolves to the `ip_addr` mentioned above. To be able to translate `host_name` to `ip_addr`, either you have to create an appropriate entry in the `/etc/hosts` file of the web "browser" machine or an entry in the DNS server which will eventually be referred by the "browser" machine. Please, note that the mentioned DNS server(s) need not be public DNS servers.

---

### Notes:

The main configuration file of Apache Web Server is generally called  `httpd.conf` and it should be somewhere under `/etc`. However, in my configuration (Ubuntu + Apache2) it is at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. Virtual hosts (virtual sites) can be defined under the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` directory. Please, note that extra configuration files are "included" by using directives in the main configuration file. For this reason, to determine which additional files are "included" in your configuration, your should look at the main configuration file:

```
grep -i include apache2.conf
```

---

### For more information:

1. https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html
2. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/configuring.html

Comment: After configuring a virtual server - file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` disappears?

Comment: No. It remains as a fall-back or "catch all" site... In that case, you can edit the home page of this site to indicate that, for example, "there is not such site on this server" or whatever you like...

Comment: `cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` outputs: `cat: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf: No such file or directory`. Sometimes the file disappears...

Comment: For more information you can look at: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html